# Eval() problems in PHP

Tags: php

```
function funct($matches)
{
$fff = "hello";
$var1 = 'fff';
eval("\$woot = \$$var1;");
echo $woot;
}
```

Why won't something like this work? I've been screwing around with it for a while. I want the echo to print "hello", but I am clearly missing something :(

Thanks!

Comment: Running the interior part of your function works fine for me.

Comment: See it at [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UUkpjv)

Comment: Of course, you could do this without `evil` using variable variables: `$woot = $$var1;`.

Comment: Argh well that is just frustrating! I guess the problem must be elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what your error is but your code seems to work fine ...

here is some play around

```
$value = " xxx";

function funct() {
    $fff = "user";
    $var1 = 'fff';
    eval ( "\$woot = \$$var1;" );
    echo $woot;
}

function funct1(&$value) {
    $fff = "1222728";
    $var1 = 'fff';
    eval ( "\$value = \$$var1;" );
    echo $value;
}

funct ();
funct1 ( $value );
```

Output

```
 user1222728
```